# Python: Running Instapy on heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I am trying to create a instagram bot on heroku. I am new to this, I don't know where the tracebacks are going. `heroku logs --tail` Isn't much of a help.

What I did so far:

On the terminal:

`heroku buildpacks:add heroku/chromedriver master`

`heroku buildpacks:add heroku/google-chrome master`

Procfile:

`web: gunicorn routes:app`

routes.py:

```
from instapy import InstaPy
from instapy.util import smart_run
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)
# login credentials
insta_username = ''
insta_password = ''

# get an InstaPy session!
# set headless_browser=True to run InstaPy in the background
session = InstaPy(username=insta_username,
                password=insta_password,
                headless_browser=True,
                nogui=True)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    with smart_run(session):
        """ Activity flow """
        # settings
        session.set_relationship_bounds(
            enabled=True,
            delimit_by_numbers=True,
            max_followers=4590,
            min_followers=45,
            min_following=77)

        # actions
        session.like_by_tags(["natgeo"], amount=10)

    return 'Done'
```

Comment: Did you run InstaPy on Heroku, successfully?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to change your Procfile to this:

```
web: gunicorn app:app --log-file=-
```

for logging. Mine says app:app because my py file is called app, yours should say:

```
web: gunicorn routes:app --log-file=-
```

Also, I prefer to use the command:

```
heroku logs -t -a <insert app name here>
```